# Build an existing ionic2 app using windows phone platform

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic2, visual-studio-2017

I have ionic2 app that already works on (Android & IOS) platforms.
After I have copied the source folder to Win7 and downloaded the requirements 
I did

```
1) ionic cordova platform add windows@6.0.0

2) cordova build windows -- --appx=8.1-phone
```

I got a .sln file in platform/windows folder and output in platforms/windows/AppPackages folder.

but the output .appx file was too small (3.625 K)  just like an empty app with splashscreen (contains cordova icon).

Here is the end of the second command

[image]

The cordova requirements 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by creating a new ionic app

```
ionic start MyIonicProject tutorial
```

and replaced the src folder and every thing what I need from my app with the current .
and after that

```
ionic cordova platform add windows@6.0.0
cordova run windows
```

It works like a charm :)
I tried every thing else and didn't get any result.

Answer (score 0):

To build apps for Windows Universal, download and install Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. During the installation, Select “Tools for Cross Platform Development” as well as the SDK for Windows Universal Apps.

With everything installed, you’ll be able to add a windows platform from the command line with this command:

```
ionic cordova platform add windows
```

By default the build command produces two packages: Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1, which Ionic does not support. To upgrade Windows package to version 10 the following configuration setting must be added to configuration file (config.xml).

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
```